# Unrecognized document structure pdfmake

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy generando un pdf con la librería pdfmake y al añadir un footer con imagen y texto me falla la descarga por la imagen.

Así genero el footer:

```
async footer(currentPage, pageCount) {
    return {
      table: {
        widths: ['*'],
        body: [
          [
            await that.getImage(),
            { text: currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount, alignment: 'right', style: 'normalText', margin: [0, 0, 40, 15] }
          ]
        ]
      },
      layout: 'noBorders'
    };
}
```

y la función that.getImage():

```
private getImage() {
   return this.common.getImage().then(data => {
     return {
       image: 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data))),
       width: 100,
       height: 20,
       margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
     };
   });
```

}

creo que es por que el no tiene el valor de la imagen, por que si cambio `that.getImage()` por `{ text: 'test', alignment: 'left' }` no falla.

Adjunto imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]